# JavaScript event listener for all buttons in table Event Delegation?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have been using oneclick methods forever and am rewriting my website and want to switch to a modern of doing things (event listeners)

I understand how to add an event listener.

```
Const button = document.getElementById('button'); 

button.addEventListener('click');
```

I could loop through all the buttons but how would I properly event delegate?

Basically I have a table. And I want to target every button in it that has a specific class “edit-user” and listen for any of those buttons being clicked.

Thanks, but confused at best way to event delegate and target specific elements and having one event listener for entire table. Seems bad to add 50 different listeners for each button.

Comment: event delegation only works in a hierarchical context of the DOM (parent element to childs elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event Delegation  works on this way:
( more easy with the use of [element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches]) )

```
<table id="my-table">

 ...

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="edit-user">aaa</button>
 ...

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="edit-user">bbb</button>
 ...

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="other-class">ccc</button>
 ...
```

```
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-table')

myTable.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button.edit-user')) return // reject other buttons

  console.log( e.target.textContent)  // show "aaa" or "bbb"

  // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, note that you can add new buttons dynamically and it still works the way that's not possible when you add an event listener to each element, so in my example there is a button `"add more buttons"` that adds more buttons dinamically to demonstrate that all are clickable the same way.

```js
var butCont = document.querySelector("#buttons-container");
butCont.onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    //to prevent hiding the snippet with the console
    console.clear();
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
};

for(var i = 0;i < 50; i++) {
  butCont.innerHTML += `<button>${i + 1}</button>`;
}

//don't worry the .querySelector will get the first button which is the add more buttons one and not other button
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  butCont.innerHTML += `<button>${i += 1}</button>`;
}
```

```css
#buttons-container {
  width: 300px;
}
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button style="width: 300px;">add more buttons</button>
<div id="buttons-container">
</div>
```